# Mat table common template not loading

Tags: mat-table

Trying to create a generic table which will accept columns from TS file and loads the data.

Getting this error :

> ng:///AppModule/TableBasicExample.ngfactory.js:56 ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "[object Object]".

Code:

```
/*
* @title Basic use of <table mat-table>
 */
@Component({    
  selector: 'table-basic-example',    
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],    
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',    
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {     
  displayedColumns: Column[] = [    
    {headername:"name", field:"name"}    
  ];
  dataSource : MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement> = new MatTableDataSource();    

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);    
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);        
    console.log(this.displayedColumns,"columns");      
  }
}

<table #table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">        

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.    
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row  
  definition" -->   

  <!-- Position Column -->

  <ng-container *ngFor= "let column of displayedColumns"  
  [matColumnDef]="column.headername">   
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.headername}}</th>    
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element}} </td>               
  </ng-container>    
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>    
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got into the same bug and solved it by adding a string array with only the properties of the columns:

```
public columnsProps: string[] = this.displayedColumns.map((column: Column) => column.field);
```

Then you have to use this new array instead the displayedColumns array in the 'mat-header-row' and 'mat-row' tags:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsProps"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let elemento; columns: columnsProps"></tr>
```

I guess the error is saying that mat-row is searching for the row with the 'matColumnDef' equals to each of the columns provided but it is receiving an object instead the property itself, if it is an object, it doesn't know what property to use.

Comment: thanx its  working, but what about column header? how could i use that when i convert my columns to simple string array ( i know i could find real one by workarounds) , but it's not the right way

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution by reading the docs carefully :)

in ts:

```
public DisplayColumns: string[] = this.Columns.map((column: IBaseColumn) => column.field);
```

my view:

```
   <mat-table *ngIf="DataSource && DisplayColumns" #table [dataSource]="DataSource">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.field">
        <th mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ row[column.field] }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="DisplayColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: DisplayColumns"></tr>
    </mat-table>
```

you have to send column names to table and matHeaderRowDef and use your normal Columns in ngFor

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a new array and passed to the "*matHeaderRowDef" and "*matRowDef". As an example, I have a table component like this:

```
<app-table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [displayedColumns]="[
    { title: 'Reference', value: 'id' },
    { title: 'Date created', value: 'createdDate' },
    { title: 'Status', value: 'status' },
    { title: 'Amount', value: 'amount' }
  ]"
></app-table>
```

As you can see I'm sending "displayedColumns" to my table. Now on the component
`table.component.ts` you need to create a new var which holds only the strings from "displayedColumns":

```
public columnNames: any[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
  // init custom table columns
  for (const column of this.displayedColumns) {
    this.columnNames.push(column.title);
  }
}
```

The template `table.component.html` should look like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" matColumnDef=" 
   {{column.title}}">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef id="col.title">
    {{ column.title }}
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ element[column.value] }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnNames"></tr>
<tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnNames"></tr>
```